# I am using saxon-js and having issues with compiling/viewing in chrome

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon-js

The XSL will compile to the .sef file but in the inspect of firefox I get "Transformation failure: Error XPDY0002 at line #34  Focus for . (dot) is absent".

From my very limited knowledge, this saxon error is from not making a template the main template so why would it be tripped on a for-each?

The XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ixsl="http://saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  xmlns:js="http://saxonica.com/ns/globalJS"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template" match="/">
    <h1 align="center">Pack Schedule</h1>
    <table border="3" align="center" >
      <tr>
        <th>Complete by</th>
        <th>How Many Days Past</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="order/job">
        <xsl:sort select="Complete_by"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dueDateOP" select="xs:date(Complete_by)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="daysOut" select="(current-date() - $dueDateOP)"/> 
        <xsl:variable name="daysOutDated" select="fn:days-from-duration($daysOut)"/>              
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$daysOutDated &gt;= 14">
            <tr bgcolor="red">
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Complete_by"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="$daysOutDated" /></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <tr bgcolor="yellow">
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Complete_by"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="$daysOutDated" /></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose> 
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pack3.xsl" ?>
<order>
  <job> 
    <Complete_by> 2022-05-17</Complete_by>
    <Comments> </Comments>
    <Updated> 5/26/2022 10:05:31 AM</Updated>
  </job> 
  <job> 
    <Complete_by> 2022-05-27</Complete_by>>
    <Comments> </Comments>
    <Updated> 5/26/2022 10:05:31 AM</Updated>
  </job> 
  <job> 
    <Complete_by> 2022-05-24</Complete_by>
    <Comments> </Comments>
    <Updated> 5/26/2022 10:05:31 AM</Updated>
  </job> 
    <job> 
    <Complete_by> 2022-06-17</Complete_by>
    <Comments> </Comments>
    <Updated> 5/26/2022 10:05:31 AM</Updated>
  </job> 
    <job> 
    <Complete_by> 2022-04-17</Complete_by>
    <Comments> </Comments>
    <Updated> 5/26/2022 10:05:31 AM</Updated>
  </job> 
</order>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    <title>Days spent</title>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="saxon-js/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        SaxonJS.transform({
          stylesheetLocation: "pack3.sef.json"
        }, "async");
      }  
    </script>    
    <script>console.log(SaxonJS.getProcessorInfo())</script>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <h1>There is an error</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem. How do you run the transformation? Your code shows only a named template `xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template"`, so that code is run without a context item/node.

Comment: Assuming you want your XSLT (with Saxon-JS or any processor) to process and match nodes from an XML document you use a `match` attribute on your template e.g. `<xsl:template match="/">`, that way, the template would match an XML document node and your `for-each select="order/job"` would try to process the `job` children of the `order` root element.

Comment: I am using saxon-js (Trying to keep this on the browser). I updated the template with match.

Comment: Do you still get the same error at the same stage (compilation?)? Or now when trying to run the compiled `sef.json` file? I think your JavaScript call of `SaxonJS.transform` lacks the `'sourceLocation' : 'jobs.xml'` property on its argument.

Comment: And probably `destination: 'replaceBody'`, too.

Comment: Oh man, thank you I was looking at examples and none of them had the sourceLocation and I like the destination tip also I was going to the <xsl:result-document href="#body"> tag. Working 100%. Thank you